# Data imported to Excel as "general", text started with "=", getting "#name?" Is there a way to get it back to text?

Tags: vba, excel

On of our offices started their text data with an equals sign, which, when imported into the spreadsheet, gave the #NAME? error.

Now, I know I can change the cell format to text and then click in the formula bar, and excel recognizes the cell as text, but is there a way to do this through VBA?

EXAMPLE:

Cell display value: #NAME?

cell text =-Notice, ABC

Desired OUTPUT:  Notice, ABC

now, normally, I'd do something like

```
sub convert_it()
  if left(cells(1,1).value,2) ="=-" then cells(1,1).value = _
  right(cells(1,1).value, len(cells(1,1).value) -2)
end sub
```

but that returns a type mismatch error.

Is there some way I can get the text in the cell without manually clicking?

I can click a few thousand times and then Excel recognizes it as text again, and not as an error, but I'd rather avoid that.

Comment: What's the literal cell formula say? `=-Notice` which returns `#NAME`? And you want just `=Notice`? Are you sure there's a UDF with that name, or a formula with that name, in your Excel version?

Comment: @BruceWayne it's supposed to be an informational message, so I just want the message, what was input was the message with a leading "=-", so if it says "=- Notice, XYZ", all I want is the "Notice, XYZ", or even getting rid of the #name? would be good enough.  I just need the data usable and not sitting in there as an error

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with VB, or just highlight the whole sheet, hit CTRL-H, type **=** in the Find and **'=** in the Replace, then click Replace All.  This will make Excel stop thinking that these are formulas.

Comment: This is probably the quickest/easiest way. To be sure, OP could Find `=-Notice` and replace `'=-Notice`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.Value` you have to use `.Formula`, since it's being interpreted as such here:

```
sub convert_it()
  if left(cells(1,1).formula,2) ="=-" then cells(1,1).formula = _
  right(cells(1,1).formula, len(cells(1,1).formula) -2)
end sub
```

[image]

Naturally you would place your code within a loop for the column. But I agree that it might be easier to just do a large find/replace.